# R: GLM dropping a few of my variable levels in the output

Tags: r, glm, binomial-coefficients

I'm aware that this question has now been asked a few times and have all the replies that I could find but still, I slightly different case:

I have a model predicting `Acc` by two factors, namely `Condition` and `Language`, each of them with two levels (Switching vs. Nonswitching; Language 1 vs. Language 2). I want to see the coefficient for all levels, including their interactions. So what I have is:

```
acc_summary <- summary(glm(Acc ~ Language*Condition, 
                           family = "binomial", data = my_dataset))
print(acc_summary)
```

My output to that is:

```
    > print(acc_summary)

Call:
glm(formula = Acc ~ Language * Condition, family = "binomial", 
    data = my_dataset)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.0528   0.5092   0.5762   0.6023   0.6076  

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                  1.9773     0.1100  17.968   <2e-16 ***
LanguageL2                  -0.3622     0.1534  -2.361   0.0182 *  
ConditionSwitch             -0.2659     0.1518  -1.751   0.0799 .  
LanguageL2:ConditionSwitch   0.2466     0.2111   1.168   0.2427    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2393.8  on 2817  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2385.6  on 2814  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2393.6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

I'm aware that the alphabetically first levels will be used as intercept (L1 and Nonswitch). However, if my `LanguageL1:ConditionNonswitch` is intercept for my interaction, what happened to the `LanguageL1:ConditionSwitch` and `LanguageL2:ConditionNonswitch`? I tried adding a `+0`, then I would just see the following:

```
   Call:
glm(formula = Acc ~ Language * Condition + 0, family = "binomial", 
    data = my_dataset)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.0528   0.5092   0.5762   0.6023   0.6076  

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
LanguageL1                   1.9773     0.1100  17.968   <2e-16 ***
LanguageL2                   1.6151     0.1069  15.115   <2e-16 ***
ConditionSwitch             -0.2659     0.1518  -1.751   0.0799 .  
LanguageL2:ConditionSwitch   0.2466     0.2111   1.168   0.2427    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 3906.6  on 2818  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2385.6  on 2814  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2393.6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Seeing my coefficient for my LanguageL1:ConditionSwitch is very important for me in the case of this experiment. I don't understand well how `glm` works, so any advice would be of great help. Thank you!

Comment: Factors are converted into binary dummy variables. This leads to the base level of the factor being omitted. If you want another base level, you can use `relevel()`. The case where all variables the base level is represented by the intercept, although in the second output here you have defined it to be zero in your formula, which is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Hi @shs and thanks for the response. I'm not sure I understand well, though. I'm fine with the base levels being omitted but am not sure for my interaction, where did the other 2 levels (excluding the base one and the one displayed) have gone...

Also for `relevel()` I seem to get an error message saying that my factors are not unordered.

Answer (score 0):

**I got someone answering my doubts in person, so I'll post their answer summarised here for future reference of others:**

Apparently, if there is a 2 X 2 interaction, I should only get one coefficient for the interaction, which denotes how much extra I have to apply to just the L2 and Switch condition. It doesn’t really matter for how things are coded / releveled in this case, and I will always only get one coefficient for the interaction. The significance of that coefficient  is equivalent to the significance of the overall interaction.

Comment: But why don't we have LanguageL1:ConditionSwitch and LanguageL2:ConditionNonSwitch?

Comment: For what I get, this is just the way the above is notated. As in, the interaction gives only one coefficient. The "L2" and "Switch" come from the way R codes contrasts.